# "HideIfNoRows"=False not performing as expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, grouping, visibility

In my report, I have 4 different row groups, each has "HideIfNoRows" property on its static row set to False. In spite of this, when a group doesn't have any row, the static row disappears. I need to show the group row even if it has no data in it, i want it to be empty.

Comment: How can we see the 'HideIfNoRows' property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a group header that does not have this property if you are only interested in having a section title to display. 
If you want the full functionality of a record to print with no data then you are better off setting this property to false and adding a phantom record in your data, set with nulls, that will always exist with or without "real" data.

Comment: Another option would be, and I do not know your grouping level, would be to add a group expression to 1=1. This will always print at least one record for the group, regardless of data.

Comment: I don't have a change to try it right now, but I like these ideas and I think they would work for me.